Can a Holy Symbol for a cleric or paladin be set into jewelry?
In the Player's Handbook (p.151) it says that a Holy Symbol can be "carefully engraved or inlaid" onto a shield.
I was wondering if this could be done with jewelry, e.g. a set of rings and earrings. It just seems like a very practical way of having your Holy Symbol with you at all times - even while sleeping. If my PC had the Holy Symbol engraved into the jewelry he wears, then he'd be always at the ready.
I'm going to ask whether my DM would permit this at his table but I want to know what the RAW answer would be to this?
